# multiple background for an input box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have multiple backgrounds(1. #fff, 2)img 3)gradient background. But it doesn't seem to work

Here is the of what my output should look like

CODE SAMPLE

```
<div id="send-date" class="transaction-details">
        <label for="date">Send on</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
</div><!-- /send-date -->

#send-date input {
    background: #fff,
                url(../img/icon_calendar_36x36.png), 
                linear-gradient(btop, #FFFFFF 30%, #BFCBFB 65%, #869CFF 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%, 96% 50%, 0% 0%;
    background-size: cover, 24px, cover;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#send-date input.ui-focus{
    background-image: url(../img/icon_calendar_36x36.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 96% 50%;
    background-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #a18492;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 8px #AAAAAA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 8px #AAAAAA;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 8px #AAAAAA;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/dpWrG/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from [this article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/) that gradients in css3 are generated as images and can be used instead of url(foobar);

So my guess is that they may not play too well with images in the same element.

Try a transparent overlay on your background gradient with the image. Or the other way around.